# Python - merge repeating characters (ins sequence) in string?

Tags: python, string

When I have specific character that repeats more than once in a sequence, I want to merge it, so there won't be same adjacent characters.

For example:

```
s = 'aa.bc.a.d.aaa.z'
# after merging repeating "a" character in a sequence:
```

**Output should be**: `a.bc.a.d.a.z`

P.S. I was able to find start and end indexes of such matches (with regex), but still can't see normal way of just merging those like I need.

Just to clarify how I found it:

```
import re
f = re.finditer('(a){2,}', s)
for match in f:
  match.span()
(0, 2)
(10, 13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
s = ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby('aa.bc.a.d.aaa.z'))
```

Comment: This ones interesting

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\D)\1+', r'\1', s)
'a.bc.a.d.a.z'
```

Comment: Why a non-digit (`\D`) only? Looks like OP needs to match any character.

Comment: It's a trivial replacement

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string = 'aa.bc.a.d.aaa.z'
res = ""
for c in string:
   if not res.endswith(c):
   res += c
```